# Как правильно написать в письме: доступ в систему специалистов или специалистам?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Обеспечить доступ в систему *специалистов* или *специалистам*?

Answer (score 1):

Лучше написать так: **Обеспечить специалистам доступ в систему.** Если имеется в виду, что специалистам обеспечивают доступ в систему. А что такое **система специалистов** без контекста понять сложно. Поэтому для более точного ответа нужен контекст.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант исправления:

**Обеспечить доступ специалистов в систему.**

В остальном см. ответ Сержа.